# Configure Grails application to use Oracle driver in development but not include it when building the war

Tags: oracle, grails

I have configured my application to use Oracle when running in the development environment by adding the driver jar in the lib directory and by refreshing dependencies. Then, when I build the application, Grails includes this driver jar in the war file. My goal is to avoid including the driver jar in the war file since I will deploy the application in a Tomcat Server that already has this driver.

Grails version: 2.1.1

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would say that's what scope provided is for:

```
dependencies { 
    provided 'oracle:oracle-driver:6.66' 
}
```

With this scope the dependency is added in development but is not included into packed war because it's expected to be PROVIDED by the runtime environment where the WAR is going to be deployed.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest defining the dependency in your `BuildConfig.groovy` file instead of dropping the jar into the lib directory manually.  In the `BuildConfig.groovy` you should have a dependencies block.  Inside of that you can add your dependency

```
dependencies {
    build('ojdbc:ojdbc:14')
}
```

Inside of the `BuildConfig.groovy` you can add a block like this that will remove it from the war as well when you build it ([Stackoverflow on removing files from war](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15062033/how-can-i-exclude-plugins-jar-required-at-build-time)):

```
grails.war.resources = { stagingDir ->
    //you can use wild cards or explicitly remove it
    delete(file:"${stagingDir}/WEB-INF/lib/ojdbc*.jar")
}
```

Comment: Right now I'm using the "grails.war.resources" configuration option to add extra processing before war file is totally created, but I'm still having the jar in the lib directory and refreshing dependencies.
In my opinion it should not be the best solution since Grails has a dependency mechanism for this purposes. Now I'm working in this line and I'm trying to include my local Oracle JDBC client jar in the local repository of ivy (or maven) in order to use it later in the block dependencies of the BuildConfig.groovy file, ideally, using the "provided" scope, as lukelazarovic suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you looking for Gradle or Maven ,
 would recommend using the grails-gradle-plugin instead.
 cleanup and usage of bootstrap scope to exclude Tomcat jars from war.

General info

on Youtube at gr8conf 2013. I was able to create a small POC and Gradle seems to work fine with Grails 2.1.1.

Gradle build file

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/' }
    maven { url 'http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo' }
    maven { url 'http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins' }
    maven { url 'http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release' }
    maven { url 'http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external' }
    maven { url 'http://repository.springsource.com/maven/libraries/release' }
    maven { url 'http://repository.springsource.com/maven/libraries/external' }
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT',
    'org.grails:grails-bootstrap:2.2.3' 
  }
}

version='0.0.1'

apply plugin: 'grails'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  maven { url 'http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/' }
  maven { url 'http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo' }
  maven { url 'http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins' }
  maven { url 'http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release' }
  maven { url 'http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external' }
  maven { url 'http://repository.springsource.com/maven/libraries/release' }
  maven { url 'http://repository.springsource.com/maven/libraries/external' }  
}

grails {
  grailsVersion '2.2.3'
  version '2.2.3'
}

configurations {
  all {
    exclude module: 'commons-logging'
    exclude module: 'xml-apis'
  }
  test {
    exclude module: 'groovy-all'
  }
  compile {
    exclude module: 'hibernate'
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile( "org.grails:grails-crud:$grails.grailsVersion",
           'org.grails:grails-gorm:1.3.7')

  bootstrap "org.grails:grails-plugin-tomcat:$grails.grailsVersion"
}
```

[Refer this Stackoveflow question :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359014/how-to-tell-grails-to-use-gradle-for-dependencies-resolution)